# Adding new Records to Firebase database using email of user on IOS swift Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to add a new record for every user who has registered on my application using their email not uid,
this is the code i have is using uid. any suggestions?

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
            ref.child("users/(user.uid)/Experience").setValue(experience)
            ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["displayName": name])
            ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["Number": number])
            ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["Age": age])
            ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["Height": height])
            ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["Experience": experience])
```

Answer (score 0):

let email = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.email

let userCurrently = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

let emailQueried = userCurrently?.email